# Java loop to output patttern based on integer value and letter character

Tags: java, loops, count

This has been boggling my mind for over an hour now trying to get this to do the reverse of what it's already doing, I can't seem to get it working!

Basically I've got the first part working where the user inputs an integer and a character so for example:

Integer: 5
Character: X

This will then output

X
XX
XXX
XXXX
XXXXX

The code which I have for this is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Integer: ");
        int userInt = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Letter: ");
        String userLetter = scan.next();
        String letter = "";
                for (int i = 0; i <= userInt; i++) {
                    System.out.println(letter);
                    letter += userLetter;
                }


    }}
```

But I now need it to do the reverse so that once it's reached it's maximum integer count then it'll reverse back just to one letter like the following:

X
XX
XXX
XXXX
XXXXX
XXXX
XXX
XX
X

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this [Java tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0080__Statement-Control/PrintoutaDiamond.htm). You'll get a good idea of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a loop that runs in reverse order...

```
for(int i = userInt; i > 0; i--) {
    letter = letter.substring(0, letter.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(letter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a String, you could save your character input in a char variable 
and then just print from j=1 to userInt and then again from userInt -1 to 1

```
    char userLetter = scan.next().charAt(0);; 
    int userInt;
    for ( int j = 1; j <= userInt; j++){                                                                                 
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            System.out.print(userLetter);        
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for ( int j = userInt-1; j > 0; j--){                                                                                 
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            System.out.print(userLetter);        
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```